# Solana Explorer - customUrl

Tags: explorers

I'm trying to connect https://explorer.solana.com to a custom cluster using the "Custom RPC URL". The description says `Enable this setting to easily connect to a custom cluster via the “customUrl” url param.` so I'm asssuming I am trying to do as the program is intended and connect to a cluster with its own genesis, validators and RPC nodes.

I'm not trying to connect to localhost...I am trying to connect to an rpc that is on a different genesis from mainnet, testnet or devnet...

The custom cluster never pulls any stats from my network.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I have a custom cluster and I am trying to get SE to poll it.

Answer (score 2):

Many browsers like Chrome block connections to localhost, but Firefox allows it, so be sure to do this in Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, localhost works for me using Chrome. Perhaps this flag in chrome enables it?
`chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`